# Getting parseerror for AJAX call via structural functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating an API. This is my PHP Function.

```
function get_schools($cn){
    $schools = "SELECT * FROM schools";
    $school_result = mysqli_query($cn, $schools);
    $response_array['form_data']['schools'] = '';
    $school_array = array();
    while ($school_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($school_result)) {
        $school_array[$school_row['school_id']] = $school_row['school_name'];
    }
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
    $response_array['form_data']['schools'] = $school_array;
    echo json_encode($response_array);
}
```

And this is my js.

```
getSchools();

function getSchools(){
    var requestDATA = {
        'request': 'get_schools'
    }
    myApp.showIndicator();
    serverRequest(requestDATA, getSchoolsSuccess, responseError, true, true);
}

function getSchoolsSuccess(){
    if(hideIndicator){
        myApp.hideIndicator();
    }
    console.log(data);

    if(data.status == 'success'){

    }else if (data.status == 'error'){
        requestFailure(data.status, data.message, showAlert);
    } else if (data.status == '') {
        requestFailure(data.status, data.message, showAlert);
    }
}

/* AJAX Request Function */

function serverRequest(requestDATA, successCallback, errorCallback, hideIndicator, showAlert){
var METHOD = "POST";
    var serverURL = 'http://localhost/istudy/server.php'; //Path to Server.php
    var DATA_TYPE = 'json';
    var TIMEOUT = 20000;
    console.log(requestDATA);
    $$.ajax({
        url: serverURL,
        data: requestDATA,
        dataType: DATA_TYPE,
        type: METHOD,
        timeout: TIMEOUT,
        success: function(data){
            successCallback(data, hideIndicator, showAlert);
        },
        error: function(a, b, c){
            errorCallback(a, b, c, hideIndicator, showAlert);
        }
    }); 
}

/* Function to handle request error */

function responseError(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown, hideIndicator, showAlert){
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
    var error_message = "";
    switch(textStatus){
        case 'error':
        error_message = "Please check your internet connection and try again.";
        break;
        case 'parsererror':
        error_message = "Internal error occureed. Report application administrator about this error.";
        break;
        case 'timeout':
        error_message = "Slow internet may be. Pull down to refresh page.";
        break;
        case 'abort':
        error_message = "The request was aborted.";
        break;
        default:
        error_message = "Cannot reach server at this time. You can report this error.";
        break;
    }
    if(hideIndicator){
        myApp.hideIndicator();
    }

    if(showAlert){
        myApp.alert(error_message, "Oh Snap! :(", null);
    }
}

/* Request With Server Fail or Error or Others */

function requestFailure(status, message, showAlert){
    if(showAlert){
        if(status == 'error'){
            myApp.alert(message, 'No Data Available!', null);
        }else if(status == ''){
            myApp.alert(message, 'Request Failure!', null);
        }else{
            if(showAlert){
                myApp.alert("Application was not ready to serve this request at this time.", 'Unknown Response', null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works okay. The query gets the result in responseText as well but I get parseerror. Any idea what could be the issue?

Please see the attached image below.

[image]

What can be the issue?

Comment: No. Where would I use that?

Comment: Dome of my function are working fine. Some give me this error. I can't understand why? Some return object like shown in the image, and some display parseerror.

Comment: What does `var_dump($response_array)` say ?

Comment: Your response is not a valid `json`!

Comment: var dump says "array(2) {
  ["form_data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["schools"]=>
    array(5) {
      [3]=>
      string(3) "DPS"
      [7]=>
      string(5) "Lacas"
      [8]=>
      string(6) "School"
      [9]=>
      string(7) "Egarton"
      [11]=>
      string(11) "No 1 school"
    }
  }
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "success"
}
"

Comment: Try `echo json_encode($response_array);exit;`

Comment: @Rayon I tried but nothing happens.

Comment: there should be a problem with your response, when you simply return a string or another value, it is not really Json. check if you remove dataType: DATA_TYPE. if worked it might be utf-8 or whitespace I think

Comment: Check your response with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Rayon can you help me creating a valid json in my php function?

Comment: Try after set header.eg: 

`header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode($response_array); exit;`

Comment: @AliZia — Are you sure it is invalid ?

Comment: The response coming in $responsearray is a VALID JSON. I checked it.

Comment: @user6838959 still nothing.

Comment: Try after parse your response data using  jQuery.parseJSON eg: `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: Remove `type: METHOD,` and try...

Comment: None seems to work.

Comment: Since you are defining the `DATA_TYPE` to `json` this means the data that is coming after performing request is already converted into an array. That's why you are getting parse error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are defining the `DATA_TYPE` to `json` this means the data that is coming after performing request is already converted into an `array`. That's why you are getting `parse error`