# How can I check if my response is a string or JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want my response to be in JSON Object. But in some functions it comes as string and I want to parse it. How can I achieve this? This is my function.

```
function serverRequest(requestDATA, successCallback, errorCallback, hideIndicator, showAlert){
    var METHOD = "POST";
    var serverURL = 'http://istudy.com.pk/api/server.php'; //Path to Server.php
    //var serverURL = 'http://localhost/istudy/server.php'; //Path to Server.php
    var DATA_TYPE = 'json';
    var TIMEOUT = 20000;
    console.log(requestDATA);
    $$.ajax({
        url: serverURL,
        data: requestDATA,
        dataType: DATA_TYPE,
        type: METHOD,
        timeout: TIMEOUT,
        success: function(data){
            successCallback(data, hideIndicator, showAlert);
        },
        error: function(a, b, c){
            errorCallback(a, b, c, hideIndicator, showAlert);
        }
    }); 
}
```

And this is my responseText

```
responseText: "{"status":"success","message":"Your Order has Processed. Please Note this pin <b style=\"background-color:green;\">osIyKvAp<\/b> and send it to the admin with payment details."}"
```

**THIS IS MY PHP FUNCTION**

```
function confirm_order($id, $newarray, $cn) {
    $today = date('y-m-d');
    $expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days"));
    $total_items = 0;
    $total_price = 0;
    foreach ($newarray as $key => $val) {
        $total_items++;
        foreach ($val as $doc) {
            $total_price = $total_price + $doc->doc_price;
        }
    }

    $pin = random_string('alnum', 8);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (order_id, order_UserId, order_total_items, order_amount, date_created,order_status,order_pin)
    VALUES ('', '" . $id . "', '" . $total_items . "', '" . $total_price . "', '" . $today . "','0','" . $pin . "')";

    if (mysqli_query($cn, $sql)) {
        $order_id = mysqli_insert_id($cn);

        foreach ($newarray as $key => $val) {
            $total_docs = 0;
            $total_items++;
            $sep = '|';
            $sub_price = 0;
            $doc_list = '';
            foreach ($val as $doc) {
                $doc_list .= $doc->doc_id . $sep;
                $sub_price = $sub_price + $doc->doc_price;
                $total_docs++;
                $sep = '|';
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO cart_items (uc_id, uc_user_id, uc_course_id, uc_course_docs_id, uc_course_docs_num,uc_price,uc_order_num,uc_order_status,uc_dateBuy,uc_dateExpire)
            VALUES ('', '" . $id . "', '" . $key . "', '" . $doc_list . "', '" . $total_docs . "','" . $sub_price . "','" . $order_id . "','0','" . $today . "','" . $expiry . "')";

            mysqli_query($cn, $sql);
        }

        $response_array['status'] = 'success';
        $response_array['message'] = 'Your Order has Processed. Please Note this pin <b style="background-color:green;">' . $pin . '</b> and send it to the admin with payment details.';
    } else {
        $response_array['status'] = 'error';
        $response_array['message'] = 'An error occurred. Please try again later.';
    }
    echo json_encode($response_array);
}
```

Can I place any check to JSON.parse if and only if my response is string?

Comment: When you set `dataType: "json"` it automatically parses the response as JSON. There's no need to do it manually.

Comment: You do `echo json_encode($response_array);` but are you sure you are doing before that a `header('Content-Type:application/json')`?

Comment: Yes in my server.php, right below CORS, I am. 3rd line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your success handler.

```
data = typeof data === 'string' ? data : JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fairly simple javascript to do that:

```
if (typeof(data) == 'string') {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
}
```

If you are curious as to *why* it might not automatically parse your JSON, here are a couple common reasons:

- Invalid JSON (check with jsonlint.com)
- Not getting an `application/json` content type when expecting JSON (as set in the dataType parameter.

See also: [jQuery won't parse my JSON from AJAX query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query)

Comment: i would have to write this inside my success?

Comment: I have included html inside my message. Can that be the reason?

Comment: This is also my other question and it has the complete details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759241/getting-parseerror-for-ajax-call-via-structural-functions

Answer (score 0):

"Can I place any check to JSON.parse if and only if my response is string?"
Yes, you can.

```
if (typeof (response) != 'object'){
response = JSON.parse(response);
}
```

Comment: In your success function.  You called it `data` rather than `response`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `DATA_TYPE = 'json';` and try again:

```
function serverRequest(requestDATA, successCallback, errorCallback, hideIndicator, showAlert){
    var METHOD = "POST";
    var serverURL = 'http://istudy.com.pk/api/server.php'; //Path to Server.php
    //var serverURL = 'http://localhost/istudy/server.php'; //Path to Server.php
    var TIMEOUT = 20000;
    console.log(requestDATA);
    $$.ajax({
        url: serverURL,
        data: requestDATA,
        type: METHOD,
        timeout: TIMEOUT,
        success: function(data){
            try {
               if(typeof(data)==='string') data=JSON.parse(data);
            } catch(ex) { // bad json response
               console.error(ex);
            }
            successCallback(data, hideIndicator, showAlert);
        },
        error: function(a, b, c){
            errorCallback(a, b, c, hideIndicator, showAlert);
        }
    }); 
}
```

NOTE. This will not avoid the issue, but will let us to parse the response, while having a possibile bad response from the server i.e. a `Content-Type` that is not `application/json`. Some web server will accept both `Content-Type:text/plain` and `Content-Type:application/json;` headers, while returning in both cases a `json formatted string` rather than `json object` parsed by $.ajax (when finds the `application/json` as the `Content-Type` header value).

To achieve that, be sure in your `php` code to print out the right header

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json`)
```

Comment: I console.log(typeof(data)) and it is object. But it says parseerror. any ideas?

Comment: This could be due to a bad json object. If you do `JSON.stringify(data)` what you get?

Comment: {"status":"success","message":"Your Order has Processed. Please Note this pin <b style=\"background-color:green;\">KTDZoFxf</b> and send it to the admin with payment details."}

Comment: ok so this is a valid JSON object, so where you get this error i.e. which line? The counter proof is: `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(data) )` you will get back your json object parsed.

Comment: For some reason I can't understand that

Comment: Still not working :( Do you want to see my PHP Function?

Comment: please update the code here with both the client and the server.

Comment: In both questions the functions are a bit different. Can you just see that question?

Comment: Please check to have in your php server a `header('Content-Type: application/json`)` as well.

Comment: @AliZia if you add a `console.error(error)` in the `error:` callback and a `console.log(data)` in the `success:` callback, before any other code, what do you get in the console?

Comment: Ok so you have definitively an `error` response, now wait you have to change it a little bit! `console.log(a,b,c)` and get the output.

Comment: I have also added my php function if that would help.

Comment: I don't understand why this error is generating in just 2 3 functions and not in the rest. :(